# Can I code and test a structured text program in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plc, st

I am new to programming and want to start with structured text. I searched the internet to see if it is supported by VScode.

I installed VScode because of its popularity

Comment: look at the Marketplace, there are a few `structured text` extensions

Comment: If you want to learn PLC programming, I recommend going for something close to the real thing, use Codesys, the IDE is free, meets IEC61131-3 and allows offline simulation.